# Horizontal looping mysql inside div tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, loops

Can someone help me to make content looping similiar with [this](http://anichart.net) website?
I tried to use while() construct and it was looping vertically. It appears without using table and I assume that this page is using thumbnail.

What I really need is the items will loop every 3 items and this is the code that I wrote and appears vertically.

```html
<div class="container">

<?php

    include "config/database.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM anidata";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($query > 0) {
?>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="float: left;">
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $image = $row['image'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $genre = $row['genre'];
        $start = $row['start'];
        $schedule = $row['schedule'];
        $description = $row['description'];
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbnail" >
        <div>
            <img src="admin/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width="194" height="272">
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
            <span id="teks" style="font-size:18px;"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
            <div class="line-title">
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $description; ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="genre">
                    <span><?php echo $genre; ?></span>          
                </div>                  
            </div>             
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you want every three items horizontally then below next three items and so on right??

Comment: Did you include bootstrap css?

Comment: add a css command (float:left;) to the container div

Comment: @S.Pols yes, i included bootstrap

Comment: @sandeepKumar yup, that's what i wants. but it seems like it needs the foreach() statement. and i don't know how do i do with it :(

Comment: @DLastCodeBender already did that man, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If `.thumbnail` already have `float:left;` in your css you can remove the `style` attr.

```
<div class="container">

<?php

    include "config/database.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM anidata";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($query > 0) {
?>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="float: left;">


<div class="row">

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $image = $row['image'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $genre = $row['genre'];
            $start = $row['start'];
            $schedule = $row['schedule'];
            $description = $row['description'];
    ?>
    <div class="thumbnail" style="float:left;">
        <div>
            <img src="admin/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" width="194" height="272">
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
            <span id="teks" style="font-size:18px;"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
            <div class="line-title">
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $description; ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="genre">
                    <span><?php echo $genre; ?></span>          
                </div>                  
            </div>             
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: Maybe that's the issue that you dont have enough space. What happens if you change the image width to 50?

Comment: Nope, it's finally works for some reason. It's just the css problem , thanks for helping anyway :)